# Vectors with cout operator issue in C++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

In my program, I am encountering an error with trying to print the `end()` of a vector. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "inFrench.h"

using namespace std;

class student
{
    int m_studentNumber;
public:
    string nameFirst;
    string nameLast;
    string nameFull;
    int getStudentNumber() { return m_studentNumber; }
    void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) { m_studentNumber = studentNumber; }
};

class group
{
public:
    vector<student> groupMembers;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const student& s)
{
    return os << s.nameFirst << ' ' << s.nameLast;
}

student typeName()
{
    student bar;
    cout << "Type in a student's first name: ";
    cin >> bar.nameFirst;
    cout << "Type in that student's last name: ";
    cin >> bar.nameLast;
    bar.nameFull = bar.nameFirst + " " + bar.nameLast;
    return bar;
}

void displayStudents(student listOfStudents[50], int studentHeadCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentHeadCount; i++)
    {
        cout << listOfStudents[i].nameFull << endl;
        cout << listOfStudents[i].getStudentNumber() << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void generateGroups(int numberOfGroups, int maxStudents, int studentsPerGroup, int remainder, group foo, student theStudents[], int studentsBeenAssigned)
{
    int k;
    numberOfGroups = maxStudents / studentsPerGroup;
    cout << numberOfGroups << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (studentsBeenAssigned << maxStudents)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxStudents; j++)
        {
            k = rand() % maxStudents;
            foo.groupMembers.push_back(theStudents[k]);
            cout << foo.groupMembers.end() << endl;
            studentsBeenAssigned++;
        }
    }
    if (remainder < studentsPerGroup && remainder > 0) // Still coding this section
    {
        foo.groupMembers.push_back(theStudents[k]);
    }
}

void languageChoices()
{
    cout << "Select your language from the following:\n";
    cout << "a) English\n";
    cout << "b) French\n";
    cout << "\n";
}

void options()
{

    cout << "Select what you want to do:\n";
    cout << "1) Exit application\n";
    cout << "2) Enter a Student\n";
    cout << "3) Display Students\n";
    cout << "4) Display Groups\n";
    cout << "5) Output groups as text file\n";
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    char selectedLanguage;
    languageChoices();
    cin >> selectedLanguage;
    switch (selectedLanguage)
    {
        case 'a':
        {
            group finishedListOfStudents;
            student allStudents[50]; // Having 50 students alone is ridiculous!
            bool endProg = 0;
            int maxStudents;
            int studentsPerGroup;
            int optionSelect;
            int studentHeadCount = 0;
            int remainder = 0;
            int numberOfGroups;
            int studentsBeenAssigned;
            cout << "GroupPicker 1.0\n";
            cout << "Note: This version of the program is intended for purposes of education only, " 
            << "specifically for teacher use in a classroom.\n\n";
            cout << "How many students are in the class?\n" << "(Note: You cannot have more than 50 in this program)\n";
            cin >> maxStudents;
            if (maxStudents > 50)
            {
                cerr << "Too many students!\n" << "Exiting program...\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (maxStudents >= 35 && maxStudents <= 50)
            {
                cout << maxStudents << " students? You are a pro!\n";
            }
            cout << "How many students per group?\n";
            cin >> studentsPerGroup;
            if (studentsPerGroup >= maxStudents || studentsPerGroup <= 1)
            {
                cerr << "You're kidding, right?\n" << "Exiting program...\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }
            while (endProg == 0) {
                options();
                cin >> optionSelect;
                switch (optionSelect) {
                    case 1:
                        endProg = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    {
                        if (studentHeadCount == maxStudents)
                        {
                            cerr << "You can't enter more than " << maxStudents << " students\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            allStudents[studentHeadCount] = typeName();
                            allStudents[studentHeadCount].setStudentNumber(studentHeadCount);
                            cout << "Student (" << allStudents[studentHeadCount].nameFull << ") entered.\n";
                            cout << "\n";
                            studentHeadCount++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:
                        cout << "Current list of students:\n\n";
                        displayStudents(allStudents, studentHeadCount);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    {
                        if (studentHeadCount < studentsPerGroup || studentHeadCount < maxStudents)
                        {
                            cerr << "Invalid group parameters.\n" << "Returning to main menu...\n\n";
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "Here are the groups:\n";
                            generateGroups(numberOfGroups, maxStudents, studentsPerGroup, remainder, finishedListOfStudents, allStudents, studentsBeenAssigned);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5:
                    {
                        cout << "Saving groups to file...\n";
                        ofstream studentGroups;
                        studentGroups.open("studentGroups.txt");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'b':
        {
            mainInFrench();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) [Line 66]
IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands. operand types are: std::ostream << std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<student>>> [Line 66]
```

I have considered overloading the `ostream operator<<` operator again, but is there another option?

Comment: Please also share your code of `"inFrench.h"`.

Comment: You CAN'T print `end()`, as it's the one-past-the-end value. You probably want `back()`. I don't think that's causing your compile error, though.

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's the same as main.cpp, but the text is in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector::end()` returns [an iterator to the end of the vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) , not the actual last element.

You could print the last item like this instead:

```
cout << foo.groupMembers.at(foo.groupMembers.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Or `foo.groupMembers.back()`.

Comment: Or `foo.groupMembers[foo.groupMembers.size() - 1)]`.

Comment: But wouldn't the vector be incapable of locating values the way an array can?

Comment: @DJHead-On: nope. Check out the docs on `std::vector`, particularly `at` and `operator[]`. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I never needed the vector in the first place. I just had to use the arrays. I have answered my own question.

Comment: Using a vector will usually mean less pain later on. They take care of memory management, keeping track of the size, can ensure you don't read/write out-of-bounds etc. All this must be done manually if you use normal arrays. `std::vector` is quite often a better choice for handling a contiguous set of homogenous data.

Comment: @FredLarson That may be so, but for what I'm using them for, they're perfect.

Comment: @DJHead-On: once you get more familiar with `vector`, I think you'll find it's something of a higher-power, easier-to-use array. It's your decision based on your intended use, of course, but for most situations I would pick `vector` over a basic array.

Comment: @DJHead-On: You'll learn otherwise sooner or later. They're not perfect here. For example, your class size limit of 50. You're allocating an array of 50, even if the class size is much smaller. A vector could be sized exactly. And what if you had an auditorium-style class with 200 or more students? I had several of those in college. Arrays are a very low-level concept in C++ and fraught with peril. Note that my previous comment is a link. Read the link.

Comment: @FredLarson That is true, but it's like I wrote in the program: `cout << "Note: This version of the program is intended for purposes of education only, " << "specifically for teacher use in a classroom.\n\n";`.